# Can github pages send http requests to an external api?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, github-pages, web-hosting

I have recently developed an React app in which I made HTTP request to external API using Axios library. Then I used gh-pages to deploy it. But it doesn't even show up (it's a blank page). I know GitHub only hosts static pages. The React app is running perfectly fine on localhost.

When I host React App on Localhost using npm start and request data using HTTP GET request using Axios Library. I receive a JSON format data from the API. And I use this data to show on front end of the React App.

But when I host the react app on git hub pages and request for data using the same way. It does not send HTTP requests to the API. And hence webpage is static in nature

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. You should try to give more information with your questions. What steps are you taking? What have you tried? Are there some error messages that appear? Also, try adding a bit of code to make your point, or add a link to an external site with an example of your issue. It will improve your chances of being answered.

Comment: You can try first on your local. accessing the html on your build files. if it works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

have you tried to change `http://` to `https://`?

because  browsers nowadays don't let http requests to happen